# iOS 7 API does not work with iOS 6 with iOS 7 sdk

Tags: ios, ios7

iSO 7 introduced a new API for popover

> setPopoverContentSize: animated:

instead  of

> contentSizeForViewInPopover

which was used in iOS6 and previous. Since I am using iOS7 SDK shouldn't the first API redirect itself to use older version on iOS 6. why do I have to take care of replacing one call with if , else iOS detection everywhere in the code.

Is there a way to use one API for both the iOS version ?

Comment: No you need to wrap it in an `if statement` that checks if it can run the method using `respondsToSelector:` and then you will need to use the correct method for the correct iOS.

Comment: What is the "Deployment Target" of your app? If it's 6.x then you can keep using the older API. If your app will only support iOS 7 then update to the new API.

Comment: @rmaddy my deployment target is iOS 6.

Comment: Then use the old API and that's it. You're done. Non-issue. You won't even get any kind of deprecation warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the older call, until such a time that you feel you only need to support iOS7.

There's no way for iOS6 to know what the newer call means, so it cannot re-direct.

Comment: Except that in this case, the newer call has been available since iOS 3.2.

Comment: Great point, just upvoted your answer.  I didn't check the docs.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to use one API for both the iOS version ?

**Yes.** The only apparent change in iOS 7 is that `contentSizeForViewInPopover` is now deprecated. The other call, `-setPopoverContentSize:animated:`, and the corresponding `popoverContentSize` property [have been available since iOS 3.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPopoverController/setPopoverContentSize%3aanimated%3a).

Given that, the right approach is to change your code to use `popoverContentSize` and `-setPopoverContentSize:animated:`. Your code will work fine in iOS 6, and you won't have to worry about going through your code at some point in the future to remove iOS 6-only code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this situation is by using the older API call, like everyone is mentioning here. If your deployment target is 6.x, your app will compile and build against that and you're good to go.

You don't need to worry about iOS 6 / 7 support if your target isn't iOS 7.

That being said, if, in the future, you do move to a target of iOS 7, it should be the developer's responsibility to handle backwards compatibility, and not the SDK's. The SDK cannot make assumptions about your code and redirect deprecated calls to the newer version.... It just doesn't work like that, and such a system would be asking for trouble.

Also, in this case, setPopoverContentSize:animated: isn't exclusive to iOS7 and is supported as far back as iOS3.2 so you're good to go.

Comment: Good until the last sentence. The older call is in fact deprecated. It can still be used of course, in this case, but it is deprecated in iOS 7.

Comment: It's not deprecated in UIPopoverController.h and in the docs.

Comment: It's a method of `UIViewController`, not `UIPopoverController`.

Comment: OP mentioned popovers in his question.

Comment: Yes but `UIViewController` has popover-related methods including the 2nd one mentioned in the question. The 1st is a method of `UIPopoverController`.

Comment: The older call that the asker is talking about is the 'setPopoverContentSize:animated:' method that is declared in UIPopoverController.h. It is not yet deprecated, and that is what I am saying in my answer at the end. I have now edited my answer to reflect that and I hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: Agreed. I was referring to `contentSizeForViewInPopover` which is deprecated and in `UIViewController`.

Comment: No, @Sid you've got it backward. The OP asserts that `setPopoverContentSize:animated:` was introduced in iOS7 (which is wrong) to replace `contentSizeForViewInPopover`.

Comment: I need coffee to wake up. Sorry, all.

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   //code for iOS 6
} else {
   //code for iOS 7
}
```

Can be a pain, but this is the best we can do for now.

Comment: The proper thing to do is to use `respondsToSelector`, not to check the iOS version. But regardless, this isn't needed in this case anyway.

Comment: @rmaddy oh alright, I've seen it both ways. Care to elaborate why my suggestion is no good? Just curious, thanks.

Comment: It's always best to check the specific API in question. Apple states this clearly in their docs. And it's much clearer in code. You know exactly what you are checking for. And it avoid possible issues by looking for the wrong OS version.

Comment: @rmaddy makes sense thanks for taking the time to explain. ignore this post OP!